# passing a tuple into a function in another file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to pass a tuple containing a set of strings and numbers ('People', 14, 'Animals', 82) into a definition from another file but when I try to pass it to the definition, it returns an error.

The function I'm trying to pass the tuple to in another file is:

```
class Check():
def tuple_valid(self,t):
```

then this function it runs a suite of statements returning either True or False based on if the tuple is valid or not. and in my other file I'm running:

```
t = ('People', 14, 'Animals', 82)
TF_check = t.tuple_valid()
```

where TF_check is either True or False based on what the tuple_valid function returns. But when I try to run the main file, I get error: `"AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'tuple_valid'"`

so my question is: how do i call the function in the other file so that TF_check becomes either True or False without getting an error

Answer (score 0):

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'tuple_valid'

You know what does it mean?

> An `AttributeError` was raised because you called a certain `tuple_valid` method on an instance of `tuple`, but the `class` `tuple` doesn't have that method!

So the problem is caused by the way you are initializing `t`...

```
t = ('People', 14, 'Animals', 82)
```

...you are assigning a `tuple` to it.

---

If you want to add a `tuple_valid` method to the class `tuple` you just have to create a `subclass` of `tuple` and add this method:

```
class CustomTuple(tuple):
    def __init__(self, *values):
        ...

    def tuple_valid(self,t):
        ...
```

Then you will be able to initialize your `t` variable as an instance of `CustomTuple`:

```
t = CustomTuple('People', 14, 'Animals', 82)
```